# SOSL query ApexClass not returning result with Name Fields search group

Tags: apex, sosl

I'm trying to SOSL search ApexClass below.

`FIND {MyTestClass} IN NAME FIELDS RETURNING ApexClass(Name)`

The Name on ApexClass is a name field. Why this SOSL query has no record returned?

Comment: Why use SOSL here? To find Apex classes, you likely want exact rather than fuzzy or partial matches so SOQL seems a better fit. You also should not have any concerns over use of Shield even for it could be applied to Apex classes since you are doing an exact match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SearchGroup scope you mention in Name Field can work only in Standard Object.

Try this SOSL:

```
FIND {myTestClass_Test} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING ApexClass(Name)
```

Ref Link: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_in.htm